# How is VPN tunneling actually implemented?

Tags: encryption, wifi, vpn, ssh

I am new to [VPNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), have used them a few times, have read about "how they work" (which is all very high level), and am now confused about how this is actually implemented (so I can come full circle and understand what kind of security they are providing me).

It sounds like a VPN is something you install on your computer. You then perform your actions in the VPN UI (whether it's a terminal or a GUI). These "local" actions are then encrypted (what is the encryption method/protocol?) locally. Then, say I am at my house using WIFI or at the coffee shop. It uses my newly allocated public IP address (the one I've been assigned for only the past few hours), to send this encrypted data across the public internet, in the public WIFI at the coffee shop. So people can tell I am sending *something* over the internet, just not sure what (because it's encrypted). The way these articles sound, they make it sound like magic and that you get a static IP address locally which no one can see. That's not the case right? It is doing exactly what I'm saying. I ask this question to clarify and make sure I'm understanding correctly.

So then the encrypted traffic (going across the public internet, using my publicly known IP address), is sent to some remote server. That server then performs the *real* actions I was typing at my VPN terminal/GUI. It makes whatever internet requests and whatnot, or SSH's into some computer I'm targeting, and pipes the info back, encrypted, over the public internet, to decrypt it locally on my computer. Hopefully I'm still on the right track. Then that remote computer I sent my encrypted traffic to, what does it do to obscure my message or secure my message from its standpoint? Does it dynamically change its IP address? Is it situated in some remote wilderness guarded by gates so no one can intercept the traffic? How does it stay secure in sending messages to the actual target location? Or is it just the fact that the requests are no longer coming from my computer, so no one can know its me, all the security its accomplishing?

Basically, I'm wondering if this is sort of how it's implemented.

Comment: What you describe sounds not like a VPN but more like remote desktop (RDP, VNC, ...) or remote shell (i.e. SSH).  Does this answer your question? [Help understanding VPN](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84210/help-understanding-vpn)

Comment: To paraphrase a line out of OpenVPN's manpage, a VPN is not much different from a _very, very_ long Ethernet cable between two places. However, the exact protocol will depend on the implementation you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, when you do *anything* on the Internet, you do so through a **network interface**. That is the thing that "has an IP address". You can have several interfaces on your system (for example Ethernet, WiFi, and the "loopback" interface that allows two programs to talk to each other through the "internet" even if you are offline.

VPN software simply tells the system there is *another* interface, let us call it "vpn0". The system asks the interface, "do you have an IP address?" and the VPN software answers "Yessirree, it's 150.217.256.35" (*yes, that 256 is both impossible and intentional*).

Then, the VPN software (usually) also publishes a *route*, i.e., it says, "addresses from 150.217.0.0 through 150.217.511.511 are reachable through this interface" .

So whenever some program on the system wants to reach, say, 150.217.432.234, the packet will get sent to vpn0.

If the published route is the *default* route for anywhere, then *all* packets (except loopback and *local* ethernet and wifi) will be routed through vpn0.

The VPN software might *also* publish new DNS servers, so that if some program such as Google Chrome wanted to reach [www.nekkidgals.org](http://www.nekkidgals.org) (*haven't checked, but it probably exists*), it would ask that DNS instead of, say, 8.8.8.8. So *also* the packet asking "what is the IP of [www.nekkidgals.org?"](http://www.nekkidgals.org?%22) would go through vpn0.

Now vpn0 is actually a software driver, and this driver encrypts the packet. It can do this in any of several ways.

For example, before vpn0 even exists, it could connect (through eth0 or wlan0, both insecure) to a known VPN server and ask for a public key. Then it could choose a very large symmetric key for, say, AES-256 algorithm, and send this key to the server after encrypting it with the server's public key. So, even if someone was to listen on the insecure wlan0, it could not decrypt the AES256 key since it would not possess the *private* key. The server, meanwhile, *having* that private key, is now in possession of the AES256 key. VPN client and VPN server start exchanging packets protected by AES256 through wlan0.

Each time the user believes he's sending unencrypted data through vpn0, that data gets encrypted and sent to the VPN server via wlan0. There it gets decrypted and continues its journey, but now it appears as if it originated inside the network of the VPN server.

As you can see, it is important that not only the connection is encrypted, but all the routes must be covered *and* DNS needs also be tunneled through VPN. Otherwise, someone could still guess what you're doing from the DNS queries sent in the clear.

Apart from this detail, **your computer remains unchanged**, so for example if you have spyware or malware aboard, *it will still work*; if you or some software can be tricked into *not* using the VPN for something, you can be traced; and your browser is still your browser, with its cookies, its supercookies, its audio-context fingerprint, its unique combination of versions, fonts, resolution and whatever; so it can be recognized.